# Reboots to Ubuntu Grub

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I am new to Ubuntu and was installing the OS onto a flash drive. The flash drive was knocked out during the "copying files" phase of installation. After this mishap I was going to try again later but I turned the computer back on and a Ubuntu grub screen appeared, not letting me get to my Windows boot manager.

Since the files were in the copy phase of installation, I figured it would be no big deal. How can I go about getting back to the Windows side?